# Iframe Issue - Content cannot be be displayed in a frame

Tags: apex, iframe

[image]
Can anyone help me out with the below issue -

I'm facing an issue with apex Iframe in VF page while displaying Tableau related dashboards in Salesforce. When the VF page is accessed I get an error that says  'This content cannot be displayed in a frame'(Please refer to the attached image). The URL that I embedded in the frame works well when viewed on browser outside of salesforce but it doesn't work when viewed in Iframe. Also when I tried accessing the page initially, I faced a certificate error. This error got fixed when I installed the certificates to the 'Trusted Root Certification Authorities' Folder but  Installing the certificates didn't help me out.

I tried accessing the page with some browsers. Following are the errors that we got for each browser 
1. Internet Explorer - 'This content cannot be displayed in a frame' 
2. Google Chrome - Shows a blank Page
3. Firefox - ' This Connection is Untrusted'

I'm wondering if this is because of the 'Clickjack' protection that is enforced by salesforce.

Below is My Iframe Code -

```
   <apex:page standardController="Account" sidebar="false">  
      <apex:iframe  
     src="https://tableauq.idexx.com/#/site/americas/workbooks?:embed=yes"/>
   </apex:page>
```

Comment: can you check browser console log?

Comment: 2. Google Chrome - Shows a blank Page - There will be a gray color shield icon in right hand side of the address bar. Click on that and accept to display unsafe items.

Comment: there  is some page which you can not embedd as in iFrame. SO i think you need to contact with `https://tableauq.idexx.com/#/site/americas/workbooks?:embed=yes` site admin.

Comment: @Himanshu - Thanks for your response. I can see the following error in browser console   - Refused to display ' https://tableauq.idexx.com/#/site/americas/workbooks?:embed=yes in a frame because it set 'X - Frame - Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Comment: @SLman - Hi, Thanks for your reply. I don't see any grey color shield icon in the address bar.

Comment: (Official) Why iFrame in Salesforce is no longer possible: 
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=IFRAME-or-Web-Tab-Content-Displays-Blank-Page-1327107637323